# Store the enum constants in variable

Tags: enums

This code actually works fine, the question I have with my code is how do you store the enum constant in any variable, and why do we use enum? and what does the statement mean `HouseType houseType;`? Thank you so much in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HomeBuying {
    public enum HouseType{UNKNOWN,SINGLEFAMILY,TOWNHOUSE,CONDOMINIUM};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the type of house you want to purchase"); //1.Single Family/n" " 2. Townhouse/n" " 3. Condominium/n");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        HouseType houseType;
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: 
            houseType = HouseType.SINGLEFAMILY;
            break;
            case 2: 
            houseType = HouseType.TOWNHOUSE;
            break;
            case 3:
            houseType = HouseType.CONDOMINIUM;
            break;
            default:
            houseType = HouseType.UNKNOWN;
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(houseType);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you provided already stores an Enum value in a variable.

```
HouseType houseType; //declaration of variable of type HouseType (means it can store values of the HouseType enum)
houseType = HouseType.UNKNOWN; //put value into the houseType variable
```

We use enums whenever we need to represent values from some known and finite set. For example if you want your program to keep track of whether it is day or night, you could just make up some rule for yourself and use integers, say 1 represents day and 0 represents night. But then what the other numbers mean? Or you could just use boolean for that (again, with some arbitrary meaning attached to **false** and **true**).

```
enum TimePeriod{
    DAY,
    NIGHT
}
```

Enums represent a better alternative by letting you to be explicit about what values mean. This is not just a convenience - being explicit in your intentions is what makes your program readable by others.

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrew Butenko